# I have two problems, one of them is a regex

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

I am updating some code that I didn't write and part of it is a regex as follows:

```
\[url(?:\s*)\]www\.(.*?)\[/url(?:\s*)\]
```

I understand that .*? does a non-greedy match of everything in the second register.

What does ?:\s* in the first and third registers do?

**Update:** As requested, language is C# on .NET 3.5

Comment: Oh, so now you have 3 problems?

Comment: @Guy, \s is a perlish regex construct.  Can you update the question tags to show either [perl] or [pcre] (perl "compatible" regular expressions), and perhaps the actual programming language in question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax `(?:)` is a way of putting parentheses around a subexpression *without* separately extracting that part of the string.

The author wanted to match the `(.*?)` part in the middle, and didn't want the spaces at the beginning or the end from getting in the way.  Now you can use `\1` or `$1` (or whatever the appropriate method is in your particular language) to refer to the domain name, instead of the first chunk of spaces at the beginning of the string

Comment: Right... and (?:) is preferable to () whenever you don't need to refer to the captured subexpression elsewhere (such as in a backreference or in the match output): it conveys more of your intention, and (at least potentially) makes processing more efficient.

Comment: So - `(?:\s*)` matches zero or more whitespace characters, without putting it into the backreferences - which is strange because `\s*` does the exact same thing, only doesn't look as confusing ;)

Comment: @gnarf: `(?:)` is useful with alternation, ie. `(?:foo|bar)` matches either "foo" or "bar" without capture.

Comment: never said it wasn't greg - just pointing out that it was a bit pointless on `\s*`

Answer (score 4):

?: makes the parentheses non-grouping. In that regex, you'll only pull out one piece of information, $1, which contains the middle (.*?) expression.

Answer (score 2):

> What does ?:\s* in the first and third registers do?

It's matching zero or more whitespace characters, without capturing them.

The regex author intends to allow trailing whitespace in the square-bracket-tags, matching all DNS labels following the "www." like so:

```
[url]www.foo.com[/url]     # foo.com
[url  ]www.foo.com[/url  ] # same
[url  ]www.foo.com[/url]   # same
[url]www.foo.com[/url  ]   # same
```

Note that the regex also matches:

```
[url]www.[/url]      # empty string!
```

and fails to match

```
[url]stackoverflow.com[/url]  # no match, bummer
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find this Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet very helpful (hopefully). I spent ages trying to learn Regex with no luck. And once I read this cheat-sheet - I immediately understood what I previously failed to learn.

http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/regex/cheat-sheet/

Comment: I would upvote this, but funny enough, it doesn't actually answer the OP's question.

Comment: I have 99 problems, but a Regex is no longer one of them.

Comment: It didn't answer *that* question but serendipitously it answered the next question that I was going to ask so +1 for seeing into the future.

Comment: thank you Guy. I had a massive mental block when I was about to answer your question. I'm glad it helped in the end...